# What is the technical relation between a delegate (function pointer, which is written as lambda expression) and LINQ?

Tags: c#

I understand that:

1. Delegate is a function pointer and useful to pass a function as a parameter so that the function can be invoked from within another function.
2. Anonymous function means a function without a name.
3. Lambda expression is a short form syntax to write an anonymous function.

Today while learning about LINQ I came across an example which suggests that the below anonymous method is the same as the subsequent code snippet (lambda expression):

```
delegate(Student s) { return s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 20; };
```

is same as:

```
s => s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 20
```

What is the technical relation between a delegate (function pointer, which is written as lambda expression) and LINQ?

Another example is as follows:

```
Func<Student,bool> isTeenAger = delegate(Student s) { 
                                    return s.Age > 12 && s.Age < 20; 
                                };

var filteredResult = from s in studentList
                     where isTeenAger(s)
                     select s;
```

versus

```
public static void Main()
{
    var filteredResult = from s in studentList
                         where isTeenAger(s)
                         select s;
}

public static bool IsTeenAger(Student stud)
{
    return stud.Age > 12 && stud.Age < 20;  
}
```

Both the above codes return same result (first code segment is delegate function, where as the second code segment is a normal function).

Comment: LINQ methods frequently take delegates, but that's all. The two concepts are independent. Delegates predate LINQ by many years

Comment: It's almost the same thing, as if you said, for example, what's the technical relation between type `int` and my custom `Add(int a, int b)` method.

Comment: To be more precise: a delegate is not merely a function pointer, it encapsulates both a method to execute, and the instance on which to execute that method (delegates to static methods have no instance, of course, and are the closest thing to "true" function pointers). They've been part of C# since version 1, over the years they've just found more uses, and gotten more syntactic sugar and shorthands. Expression trees are the feature that was explicitly added to make LINQ possible, not delegates -- and note that none of your examples involve (runtime) expression trees, that needs `Expression`.